# Double-Click on System Menu doesn't close VS Code anymore (Windows)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-7-x64

The default action in the System Menu (top left icon or Alt-Space) is not "Close" anymore in VSCode on Windows in the last version of VS Code.

Is there a setting to set the default action ?

[image: VS Code System Menu]

```
Version: 1.28.1 (user setup)
Commit: 3368db6750222d319c851f6d90eb619d886e08f5
Date: 2018-10-11T18:13:53.910Z
Electron: 2.0.9
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
Architecture: x64
```

Comment: That would drive me crazy... (I think the official term is "System menu", though.)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question

Comment: Issue on github : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The January 2019 release of VSCode now has a setting called "Window: Double Click Icon To Close" that I think does what you're looking for.